# Core Plot: Move the legend on the plotting area

Tags: core-plot, move, legend, drag, interaction

I achieved to plot my 5 lines, but wherever I place the legend, it doesn't allow me to see clearly the interception of some lines.
There is a way to allow the user to move/drag the legend along the plotting area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You could position the legend outside the plot area so it doesn't overlap the plot or subclass `CPTLegend` and override the user interaction methods (`-pointingDeviceDownEvent:atPoint:`, etc.) to implement the dragging behavior.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'm just starting with device app, and new also in this site. I'll look then for examples overriding user interaction methods in the web.